# How can I change the backgroundColor and other properties of the popover that react-native-ui-kittens Select opens

Tags: react-native, user-interface, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to change the Select component from react-native-ui-kitten to achieve the following: [image: Goal to achieve]

However I can't for the life of me figure it out, so I ended up with this:
[image: current result]

I have tried using a custom mapping as follows (transparent-white is defined in a different file as: rgba(255,255,255,0.1)):

```json
{
  "components": {
    "Select": {
      "meta": {
        "scope": "all",
        "parameters": {
          "minWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "minHeight": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "paddingHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "paddingVertical": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "borderRadius": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "borderColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "borderWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "backgroundColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "placeholderMarginHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "placeholderFontFamily": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "placeholderFontSize": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "placeholderFontWeight": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "placeholderColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textMarginHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "textFontFamily": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textFontSize": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "textFontWeight": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "iconWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "iconHeight": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "iconTintColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "iconMarginHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "popoverMaxHeight": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "popoverBorderRadius": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "popoverBorderColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "popoverBorderWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "labelColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "labelFontFamily": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "labelFontSize": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "labelFontWeight": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "labelMarginBottom": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "captionMarginTop": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "captionColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "captionFontFamily": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "captionFontSize": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "captionFontWeight": {
            "type": "number"
          }
        },
        "appearances": {
          "synesis": {
            "default": true
          }
        },
        "variantGroups": {
          "status": {
            "basic": {
              "default": true
            },
            "primary": {
              "default": false
            },
            "success": {
              "default": false
            },
            "info": {
              "default": false
            },
            "warning": {
              "default": false
            },
            "danger": {
              "default": false
            },
            "control": {
              "default": false
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "small": {
              "default": false
            },
            "medium": {
              "default": true
            },
            "large": {
              "default": false
            }
          }
        },
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 0,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "disabled": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 1,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "active": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 2,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "focused": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 3,
            "scope": "all"
          }
        }
      },
      "appearances": {
        "synesis": {
          "mapping": {
            "paddingHorizontal": 8,
            "iconWidth": 24,
            "iconHeight": 24,
            "iconMarginHorizontal": 8,
            "placeholderMarginHorizontal": 8,
            "textMarginHorizontal": 8,
            "textFontFamily": "Inter",
            "placeholderFontFamily": "Inter",
            "labelMarginBottom": 4,
            "labelFontSize": "text-label-font-size",
            "labelFontWeight": "text-label-font-weight",
            "labelFontFamily": "text-label-font-family",
            "captionMarginTop": 4,
            "captionFontSize": "text-caption-1-font-size",
            "captionFontWeight": "text-caption-1-font-weight",
            "captionFontFamily": "text-caption-1-font-family",
            "popoverMaxHeight": 220,
            "popoverBorderRadius": 20,
            "popoverBorderWidth": 1,
            "popoverBorderColor": "transparent-white"
          },
          "variantGroups": {
            "status": {
              "basic": {
                "borderColor": "transparent-white",
                "backgroundColor": "transparent-white",
                "textColor": "#C3C2C9",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "#C3C2C9",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "transparent-white",
                    "backgroundColor": "transparent-white"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "transparent-white",
                    "backgroundColor": "transparent-white"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "transparent-white",
                    "backgroundColor": "transparent-white"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "primary": {
                "borderColor": "color-primary-default",
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-hint-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-primary-focus",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-primary-hover",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-primary-active",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "success": {
                "borderColor": "color-success-default",
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-hint-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-success-focus",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-success-hover",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-success-active",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "info": {
                "borderColor": "color-info-default",
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-hint-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-info-focus",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-info-hover",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-info-active",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "warning": {
                "borderColor": "color-warning-default",
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-hint-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-warning-focus",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-warning-hover",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-warning-active",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "danger": {
                "borderColor": "color-danger-default",
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "labelColor": "text-hint-color",
                "captionColor": "text-hint-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-hint-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-danger-focus",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-danger-hover",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-danger-active",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "border-basic-color-4",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
                  }
                }
              },
              "control": {
                "borderColor": "color-basic-control-transparent-500",
                "backgroundColor": "color-basic-control-transparent-300",
                "textColor": "text-control-color",
                "labelColor": "text-control-color",
                "captionColor": "text-control-color",
                "placeholderColor": "text-control-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-control-color",
                "state": {
                  "focused": {
                    "borderColor": "color-control-transparent-focus-border",
                    "backgroundColor": "color-basic-control-transparent-500"
                  },
                  "hover": {
                    "borderColor": "color-control-transparent-hover-border",
                    "backgroundColor": "color-basic-control-transparent-400"
                  },
                  "active": {
                    "borderColor": "color-control-transparent-active-border",
                    "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-basic-color"
                  },
                  "disabled": {
                    "borderColor": "color-control-transparent-disabled-border",
                    "backgroundColor": "color-control-transparent-disabled",
                    "textColor": "text-control-color",
                    "labelColor": "text-control-color",
                    "placeholderColor": "text-control-color",
                    "iconTintColor": "text-control-color"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "size": {
              "small": {
                "borderRadius": "border-radius",
                "borderWidth": "border-width",
                "minHeight": "size-small",
                "paddingVertical": 3,
                "textFontSize": "text-subtitle-2-font-size",
                "textFontWeight": "text-subtitle-2-font-weight",
                "placeholderFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
                "placeholderFontWeight": "text-paragraph-1-font-weight"
              },
              "medium": {
                "borderRadius": 20,
                "borderWidth": 1,
                "minHeight": "size-medium",
                "paddingVertical": 7,
                "textFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
                "textFontWeight": "text-subtitle-1-font-weight",
                "placeholderFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
                "placeholderFontWeight": "text-paragraph-1-font-weight"
              },
              "large": {
                "borderRadius": "border-radius",
                "borderWidth": "border-width",
                "minHeight": "size-large",
                "paddingVertical": 11,
                "textFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
                "textFontWeight": "text-subtitle-1-font-weight",
                "placeholderFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
                "placeholderFontWeight": "text-paragraph-1-font-weight"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Popover": {
      "meta": {
        "scope": "all",
        "parameters": {
          "borderRadius": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "borderWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "borderColor": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "backgroundColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "indicatorWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "indicatorHeight": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "indicatorBackgroundColor": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "appearances": {
          "default": {
            "default": true
          }
        },
        "variantGroups": {},
        "states": {}
      },
      "appearances": {
        "default": {
          "mapping": {
            "borderRadius": 20,
            "borderWidth": 2,
            "borderColor": "transparent-white",
            "backgroundColor": "transparent-white",
            "indicatorWidth": 6,
            "indicatorHeight": 6,
            "indicatorBackgroundColor": "transparent-white"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "SelectOption": {
      "meta": {
        "scope": "all",
        "parameters": {
          "paddingHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "paddingVertical": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "paddingLeft": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "backgroundColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "iconWidth": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "iconHeight": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "iconMarginHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "iconTintColor": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textMarginHorizontal": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "textFontFamily": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textFontSize": {
            "type": "number"
          },
          "textFontWeight": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "textColor": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "appearances": {
          "default": {
            "default": true
          },
          "grouped": {
            "default": false
          }
        },
        "variantGroups": {},
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 0,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "disabled": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 1,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "selected": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 2,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "active": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 3,
            "scope": "all"
          },
          "focused": {
            "default": false,
            "priority": 4,
            "scope": "all"
          }
        }
      },
      "appearances": {
        "default": {
          "mapping": {
            "paddingHorizontal": 8,
            "paddingVertical": 12,
            "backgroundColor": "transparent-white",
            "textMarginHorizontal": 8,
            "textFontSize": "text-subtitle-1-font-size",
            "textFontWeight": "text-subtitle-1-font-weight",
            "textFontFamily": "Inter",
            "textColor": "text-basic-color",
            "iconWidth": 20,
            "iconHeight": 20,
            "iconMarginHorizontal": 8,
            "iconTintColor": "text-hint-color",
            "state": {
              "hover": {
                "iconTintColor": "transparent-white",
                "backgroundColor": "transparent-white"
              },
              "active": {
                "backgroundColor": "transparent-white"
              },
              "selected": {
                "backgroundColor": "black",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-primary-color"
              },
              "selected.hover": {
                "background-color": "transparent-white",
                "textColor": "text-basic-color"
              },
              "disabled": {
                "backgroundColor": "background-basic-color-1",
                "textColor": "text-disabled-color",
                "iconTintColor": "text-disabled-color"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "grouped": {
          "mapping": {
            "paddingLeft": 16
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to change the popover that comes with react-native-ui-kittens Select component.